# Presenting ViewController after resetting NSUSerDefaults

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I have a reset button that resets all NSUserDeafults then it reloads to the first game of the NavigationController.

```
//Reset the NSUserdefault saved objects (No problems here)
let appDomain : NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain)
            println("button pressed")

//Present first ViewController (Having problems in this code)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

let mainViewController:ViewController = ViewController()

presentViewController(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Whats is the erroryou get? Add some more informations.

Comment: I get no errors. But when I press the button. I get a blank (black) screen

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this - but i am having some problems when using this later on... *sigh*

I wish i knew the correct way to reset the view like this - but i can't find any info.

```
           let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as! UIViewController
            var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
            vc?.presentViewController(setViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```